# Windows - New administrative user not an administrator

Tags: windows-server-2008

In Windows Server 2008, I have create a new user and added it to the Administrator group ("Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain.")

However, in most instances this user is not treated as an Administrator. For example, when logged in under the new administrative user's account, Internet Explorer treats the login as a regular user, even though IE ESC is turned of for administrators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UAC is still turned on. This means that, while unelevated, your administrator user account is actually just the same as a regular user account.

More information [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: In fact, when logged in a Administrator, and being in Control Panel > User Accounts > User Accounts, does not show the critical link "Turn User Account Control on or off.". So, I am back to start. Why would this line not show?

Comment: Do you definitely want to turn UAC off? If you really do, there are instructions all over the internet. Several ways to do it - it's in msconfig.exe, for one.